# как совместить два скрипта в google sheets? автоматическая установка даты при редактировании определенной ячейки

Tags: google-spreadsheet

у меня есть такой скрипт с просторов интернета (при внесении изменений в 10 колонке, в 11 ставится дата в 12 время):

```
function onEdit(e) {
var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
var idCol = e.range.getColumn();
var idRow = e.range.getRow();
//если внесены изменения в 10 колонку  
if ( idCol == 10 && sheet.getName() =='Рабочий лист' ) {

var vartoday = getDate();
var varnow = getTime();

//добавить в одиннадцатую и двенадцатую дату и время
sheet.getRange(idRow, 11).setValue( vartoday );
sheet.getRange(idRow, 12).setValue(varnow);



}
}

// Returns YYYYMMDD-formatted date.
function getDate() {
var today = new Date();
today.setDate(today.getDate());
//return Utilities.formatDate(today, 'PST', 'dd.MM.yyyy');
return Utilities.formatDate(today, 'GMT+03:00', 'dd.MM.yyyy');
}

function getTime() {
var today = new Date();
today.setDate(today.getDate());
//return Utilities.formatDate(today, 'PST', 'dd.MM.yyyy');
  return Utilities.formatDate(today, 'GMT+03:00', 'HH:mm');
}
```

Дело в том, что я хочу, что бы при изменениях в еще одной колонке тоже проставлялась дата изменения в двух последующих.
Если создаю отдельный второй скрипт перестает работать первый.

Подскажите как их совместить, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать так

```js
function script1(e){
  ...
}

function script2(e){
  ...
}

function onEdit(e){
  script1(e);
  script2(e);
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]